# Why I'm getting "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

views.py

```
class SearchTodo(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = todoserializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        status = self.kwargs["status"]
        return JsonResponse({"data":Todo.objects.filter(status=status)}, content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py for rest framework

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"^todo/(?P<status>\w+)$",views.SearchTodo,"SearchTodo")
router.register(r"todo",views.todoview,"todor")

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/",include(router.urls))
]
```

Axios code for filter object which has the status True

```
const data = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/True`)
      .then((res) => settasks(res.data))
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

but whenever this function run I got a 404 bad request error where I'm getting wrong.

Comment: The `get_queryset(...)` supposed to return a ***`QuerySet`*** object. Anything other than a `QuerySet` object will throw an error, sooner or later

Comment: @ArakkalAbu but it saying that URL is not found than how i can filter objects what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

as someone mentioned in a comment, the `get_queryset()` methid is supposed to return a **QuerySet** object.

try with something like

```
def get_queryset(self):
    status = self.kwargs["status"]
    return Todo.objects.filter(status=status)
```